# How can I use Ubuntu's service command to manage Ring apps?

Tags: clojure, jetty, ring

I’m using a Ubuntu VPS to host a couple of Ring web apps. I have a separate GNU Screen window for each one, and I start and stop them using `lein run` and `^C`, respectively. This works, but it feels amateurish and if anything goes wrong these services won’t be restarted automatically.

I’d like to set something up so that I can start and stop my apps using Ubuntu’s `service` command (which I already use to start and stop nginx). Is there some kind of shortcut I can use to get these apps working with the `service` command? For example, is there some Leiningen- or Ring-friendly template into which I can just insert my application’s path? Failing that, what would be the best practices for writing my own `service` script to integrate with Jetty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you want your service to run straight from your project directory, or whether you want to go through the intermediate step of creating and installing a build artifact.

Certainly during development it's more convenient to use `lein run` from your project directory. For the sake of repeatability, I'd recommend using the second approach for production systems.

The general approach would be to use the `lein uberjar` task to create a stand-alone JAR file. From there, it's pretty straightforward (though somewhat tedious) to create a script you can stick in `/etc/init.d` to run the JAR file, either directly via `java` or using [`jsvc`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html).

It looks like there's a Leiningen plugin ([lein-init-script](https://github.com/strongh/lein-init-script)) to automate the process of generating the service script, though I don't have any experience with it. You'll probably want to check that out.